# Django save override recursion not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a promo code system that automatically gets claimed by eligible users/students (specified either by a M2M or comma separated string of emails).

Here's the relevant code from the model:

```
class PromoCode(models.Model):
    students_claimed = models.ManyToManyField('Student', blank=True, related_name='promo_codes_claimed')
    claimable_by = models.ManyToManyField('Student', blank=True, related_name='claimable_promo_codes')
    claimable_by_emails = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.claimable_by_emails:
            for email in self.claimable_by_emails.split(','):
                try:
                    student = Student.objects.get(user__email=email)
                    student.claim_promo_code(self)
                except Student.DoesNotExist:
                    pass

        for student in self.claimable_by.all():
            student.claim_promo_code(self)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `claim_promo_code` method within `Student` is as follows:

```
def claim_promo_code(self, promo_code):
    if promo_code.is_claimable_by(self):
        promo_code.students_claimed.add(self)
        promo_code.save()

        print('TEST')
```

I know the `claim_promo_code` method is being called because the print statement is running; however, the user is not being added/saved to `students_claimed`. Calling the `claim_promo_code` method through other means (outside of the `save` method) works as intended.

Is there a problem with calling an object's `save` method within itself, as is the case here? How should I approach solving this?

Comment: What does 'is_claimable_by' do?

Comment: Don't do this. To link your promo code to student objects, use a ManyToManyField.